# can cacheing data into process object in node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching

While I make a blog application with node(Express, in fact, and open source in GitHub^_^),I find a thing that the global object "process"(or other global object) can be access by every user, here is the test middleware:

[image]

Maybe I should put code directly instead:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
if(req.session.user.login){
    if(!process.name) {
        process.name = {length: 0};
    }
    if(Object.keys(process.name).indexOf(req.session.user.id) === -1){
        process.name['length'] += 1;
        process.name[req.session.user.id] = req.session.user.username;
    }
    console.log('######################');
    console.log('Connection count：%d',process.name['length']);
    console.log('Memory usage:%s', parseInt(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)/(1024*1024),'MB');
}
next();
});
```

So,I think whether there has been a shortcut that put the data from somewhere(in my case ,data from Mongodb by mongoose)into memory instead of use redis(it's more a learning cost for me) but just cache data into process ---the global object in node.

I'm worried about the memory leak(or named "stackoverflow"? +_+),so i test the usage of memory by add follow code:

```
console.log('Memory usage:%s',parseInt(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)/(1024*1024),'MB');
```

The log show that when there are two user login, the usage is about 20MB.

BTW again: i understand that node V8 engine is limit the usage of memory maximum is about 700M, is this influence?
thanks in advance;
(ignore my poor english ;-))